# Injecting in to class inheriting from RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, fluxor

I am using the RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider to tirgger a refresh of an access token in blazor.

I would like to inject the IDispatcher from Fluxor, in order to dispatch new tokens once the new access code has been generated.

I cannot inject IDispatcher in to the class

If I inject in to the constructor, blazor starts with a blank screen and no error is reported.

Using the [Inject] attribute just results in a null property.

Note: I can inject IDispatcher elsewhere and is used, and it is registered in DI.

Any advice on how to dispatch a message from inside?

Im using blazor server if that makes any difference.

Comment: This might have been due to IDispatcher and IStore being implemented by the same class (`Store`). I have now separated them, so you might find that there was a circular dependency that no longer occurs.

Comment: Oh cool - ill have to go find this and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not registering your class with Dependency Injection container.

Example of `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IMyClass, MyClass>();
}
```

Then you can use like so
`razor`

```
@inject IMyClass MyClassVariable
```

`c#`

```
[Inject]
protected IMyClass MyClassVariable { get; set; }
```

If you need to do it in the component's scope, you can do something like this

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    MyClassService = ScopedServices.GetRequiredService<IMyClass>();
}
```

Check out [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server#add-services-to-an-app-1) for more info

Comment: Nah, it is in my DI container.  If i add my own service and add to DI it works fine, and lots of other things also work, i now realise.  If i miss out of DI, it actually gives me an error message.
I am trying to inject IDispatcher from Fluxor - to disaptch a state change. I guess something is not compatible here for somereason? - ill update the original question with this info.

Comment: @sianabanana makes more sense. I would recommend you add some code to see if I can help you better